# How to push messages objects to array in JSON object

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

I have a JSON object like this

```
{ "messages":["{date: 2017-8-23 12:50:05, name: aaa, msg: zzz}"]}
```

I want to push more objects to messages array after every message from user in Node.js but I only clone JSON object. How to fix this?

This is my code:

```
const JSONTemplate = (filePath, date, name, msg) => {
let obj = {
    messages: [],
};
obj.messages.push(`{date: ${date}, name: ${name}, msg: ${msg}}`); //add some data
json = JSON.stringify(obj);
fs.appendFile(filePath, json, (err) => {
  if (err) throw err;
}); }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to put real object instead of string representation

```
obj.messages.push({date, name, msg});
```

But your question is still unclear for me. There is a mistake in string representation. You can not parse back your serialized object, because you miss apostrophe in your string.

And maybe you cannot get array of multiple values, because your rewrite your array by every function call.

```
const JSONTemplate = (filePath, date, name, msg, array = []) => {
let obj = {
    messages: array,
};
obj.messages.push({date, name, msg}); //add some data
json = JSON.stringify(obj);
fs.appendFile(filePath, json, (err) => {
  if (err) throw err;
}); }
```

Comment: Doesn't help. I duplicate Obj instead of appending data to array

Comment: let obj = {
    messages: [],
};

Comment: By this line you create a new array. Maybe you need to pass previous.

Comment: Yes, I see but know I have to check if I have a json object in file my file then I can push into it's array

Comment: When file would be read, you need to parse it with JSON.parse, and then pass the array in function below. The default param says that argument would be replaced to empty array if it`s value not set.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to append JSON data first you read the file and after that you could overwrite that.

```
const JSONTemplate = (filePath, date, name, msg) => {
fs.readFile(filePath, function (err, data) {
    var json = JSON.parse(data);
   //add some data
   json.messages.push(JSON.stringify({date: ${date}, name: ${name}, msg: ${msg}})); 

   fs.writeFile(filePath, json, (err) => {
     if (err) throw err;
   });
 });  
}
```

also it's good practices to use try..catch to error handling when dealing with sync function like JSON.parse(), fs.readFileSync etc.

```
try{
   var json = JSON.parse(data);
}catch(e){
   throw e
}
```

Happy coding